# Return an array from string in which some of the words have been replaced with objects with the appropriate styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this string :

`const str = 'The world consists of many different colors. for example: red, green, blue.';`

I have a dictionary that contains matching words and styles.

```
const styles = {
    RED: 'textRED',
    GREEN: 'textGREEN',
    BLUE: 'textBLUE',
};
```

I need to get such an array from 'str':

```
[
'The world consists of many different colors. for example: ',
<span className={styles['RED']}>red</span>,
", ",
<span className={styles['GREEN']}>green</span>,
", ",
<span className={styles['BLUE']}>blue</span>,
".",
]
```

Also, letters in words can be of different case, but they should still be replaced by the object.

I'm using nextjs (react) but I don't think it matters much.

Comment: will the string varry or going to be same?

Comment: @ChetanKondawle yes, the string and possibly dictionary will vary.
Also, letters in words can be of different case, but they should still be replaced by the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string, and then use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the colours, you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array that `match` provides to create an array of `span` elements.

Note: you'll have to contain the string in a span too.

```js
function Example({ str, styles }) {

  function createJSX(str, styles) {

    const [ main, tail ] = str.split(/:\s*/);
    const colors = tail.match(/([a-z]+)/g);

    return [
      <span>{main}: </span>,
      ...colors.map(color => {
        
        const spanStyle = [
          'color',
          styles[color.toUpperCase()]
        ].join(' ');
        
        return (
          <span
            className={spanStyle}
          >{color}
          </span>
        );
      })
    ];

  }

  return (
    <div>
      {createJSX(str, styles)}
    </div>
  );

}

const str = 'The world consists of many different colors. for example: red, green, blue.';

const styles = {
  RED: 'textRED',
  GREEN: 'textGREEN',
  BLUE: 'textBLUE'
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example str={str} styles={styles} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
span { margin-left: 0.25em; }
.color:not(:last-child):after { content: ','; color: black; } 
.color:last-child:after { content: '.'; color: black; } 

.textRED { color: red; }
.textGREEN { color: green; }
.textBLUE { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what i need, but forgot that there are also commas and a dot in the str. Is it possible to fix this somehow so that they are also taken into account? I corrected the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add commas and periods using CSS. @programminggood